# What Can I Do If the Dialog Mask Layer Cannot Be Removed in the LayaAir Engine?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

When I develop Huawei quick game in the LayaAir Engine, some Dialog mask layers cannot be removed, and some can be resolved but cannot be recreated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can call the `Laya.Dialog.manager.maskLayer.removeself()` API to remove a mask layer, as shown in Figure 1.
2. If you call the `close()` method by yourself, you need to set the second `showEffect` attribute in the method to `false`, as shown in Figure 2. Otherwise, the judgment in the `close()` method cannot be executed. As a result, the closing fails, or re-enabling will not take place for the mask layer.

[image]

[image]